# windows 8 restart not working as it should

Tags: windows-8

When I do a Windows 8 Pro x64 restart, either manually or as a result of installing software or a MS Update my monitor will go into standby mode for about 15 seconds or so before I see the BIOS messages on screen.  This happens about 80% of the time for restarts.  The other times, which should be the way it works, is that my monitor might go into standby for a second or two and then come out of it with the BIOS messages displayed.  I am assuming that at the point I go into standby Windows 8 is out of the picture  A cold start of my computer boots just fine with no standby delay.

Of interest is that when I have the long standby the font for the BIOS messages are larger than normal.  So large that the right side of a line is cut of a little bit.

This all started when I had to replace a defective Corsair H100 cooler.  The H100 is not the cause as it has no connection to my mobo BIOS or monitor at all.

Anyone have any ideas on this strange problem.  I couldn't find anything in my BIOS or anything in my monitors settings.

Comment: While I don't know what the cause of your issue is, one thing to note is that "a cold boot" in Windows 8 is actually a Hybrid boot (part-hibernate, part-boot) to reduce startup time.  A restart, however, is a full boot with no hibernation.  So it's sort-of the opposite of what you may expect.

Comment: See this article for [more information on hybrid shutdown](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this hotfix which fixes some issues:

**Windows 8 restarts to a blank screen after a standard shutdown or hibernation**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2756559/en-us